# Does Craft have a discussion forum and ratings add-on?

Tags: plugins

I am thinking about switching to Craft from EE but need various add-ons such as a discussion forum and ratings function (with the ability to have sub-ratings), and advanced search. I did not see anything like that in the plugins page but wanted to be sure before making this decision.

Thanks,
Geoff

Answer (score 4):

There is no discussion forum available in craft as of now but people that need that function seem to be using Vanila Forums and just integrating with single sign-on which seems to work just fine.

There is this which could work for ratings: http://plugins.supercooldesign.co.uk/plugin/button-box which is a bit simple but depends on what you need.

There is also this which could allow 'likes' https://dukt.net/craft/like

I thought I had seen something with a bit more advanced ratings but can't seem to find it now. At the end of the day though Craft > ExpressionEngine in pretty much every way. There are very few things EE can do better than Craft and even then it's usually due to a third party add-on being available there that is not yet available in Craft due to it's maturity.

Comment: I'm not sure if Dukt Like fits the described project scope... but if it does, don't forget about [Upvote](https://craftpl.us/plugins/upvote) ;)

Comment: Wow, I feel stuck - I'm starting a complicated new site that we've been getting ready for for years, and am very wary of the complexity of EE, but don't think I can go ahead without a very well developed Ratings and Discussion system. Anyway, thanks for the info.

Comment: You could always write a plugin for anything you need that's not available. The hooks available in Craft make it pretty easy to do anything you need that's not natively possible assuming you have the PHP knowledge. Craft hands down is a better core than EE is. I primarily built sites in EE till Craft. Made the switch and can't even pretend to look back.